# Aurelia Framework/SVG/CSS Manipulation

Tags: css, svg, aurelia

I am very new on the Aurelia Framework and my goal for now is to make a template object that can load an external SVG File that can be manipulated in CSS.

For tests i tried first to just load the SVG file in my app.html and later i would make a template from this but even that is failing.

the Loading looks like this:

```
<svg viewBox="50 50 100 100" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="../gfx/smasi-logo.svg#Ebene_1"></use>
</svg>
```

with CSS data like this:

```
* {
        -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
        -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
        -webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;
}
.icon {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        fill: hsl(0, 100%, 80%);
}
```

There is a SVG box with the size and the use Element has a size, but there is nothing in there and there is no error that the file was not loaded correctly so I assume the file is loaded but there are other Problems.

What do you think could be the Problem?

Or maybe there is an alternative approach that is better?

Comment: does it load in a plain html file? i don't see anything here that is aurelia specific.

Comment: this is example of how to load an external SVG file https://gist.run/?id=6c59fd34131a8cfa29744fb1ce94de70